# Haskell Simple questions

Tags: haskell

I have two questions:

1.

```
type HTML = [HTML_element]
data HTML_element
    = HTML_text String
    | HTML_font Font_tag HTML
    | HTML_p HTML
    | HTML_ul [HTML]
    | HTML_ol [HTML]
data Font_tag = ...
```

Write a Haskell function

```
strip_font_tags :: HTML -> HTML
```

which removes all font tags (replacing them with their HTML contents)

2.

```
data Mtree a = Mnode a [Mtree a]
```

Write a function

```
print_mtree :: Show a => Mtree a -> IO()
```

which prints an Mtree. Each node should be printed on a separate line. The children of a node
should be printed on subsequent lines, indented by one more space than the line giving the value in
the node. For example, given the tree

```
Mnode 1 [Mnode 2 [], Mnode 3 [Mnode 4 []]]
```

the output should be

```
1
 2
 3
  4
```

Anyone can help me? Thank you so much !

Comment: What have you attempted so far?  This looks a lot like a homework problem that you haven't tried to solve yet.  Can you post your code first along with any error messages or unexpected behavior so we can help you with your code?

Comment: not homework, it's the sample test

Comment: It's still a problem that you have posted without any attempt to solve it.  Stackoverflow is for answering specific questions you have with problems in already written code, not for providing answers to problem statements.  If you have code that you have written already, please add it to your question.  If not, I would encourage you to write some code, then add it to your question.

Comment: I am new for haskell, there is a test later but I dont know how to solve this.

Comment: If you don't know Haskell, I can recommend the [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) book that is an excellent introduction to the language.  Beyond that, there are lots of tutorials on [FP Complete](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school) that cover the basics through very complex topics.  For further reading, [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/) provides a more project based, if slightly outdated, approach.  Beyond that, there are numerous blogs and tutorials scattered across the internet.

Comment: No problem!  I apologize if I seemed harsh at first, there are people who come to this forum looking for someone to just write code for them out of laziness.  If you have the resources to learn what you need for a test, but are unwilling to put forth the effort to learn, I'm unwilling to put forth the effort to help.  Take a look at those links, see what you can figure out, and when you get stuck writing code feel free to come back to post a new question. =)

Comment: These aren't questions, they're work orders.

Comment: Hey Qi, Stackoverflow is a bit different from most communities, it's not like a forum and the like - just pure Q&A. Unfortunately the community isn't always very welcoming and explaining.. it's even *very* unfortunate imo. And so I suggest you check out the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then the [asking section of the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).
P.S. if two questions are not related enough to be called a two-part question, you should create a question for each, even if it's right after the other. Good luck, and from me you certainly have a warm welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints:

1. With the data types

```hs
type HTML = [HTML_element]

data HTML_element
    = HTML_text String
    | HTML_font Font_tag HTML
    | HTML_p HTML
    | HTML_ul [HTML]
    | HTML_ol [HTML]

data Font_tag = Font_tag
```

We want to write a function that turns something like

```
[HTML_font Font_tag [HTML_p [HTML_text "Hello"], HTML_p [HTML_text "world"]]
-- <font><p>Hello</p><p>world</p></font>
```

Into

```
[HTML_p [HTML_text "Hello"], HTML_p [HTML_text "world"]]
-- <p>Hello</p><p>world</p>
```

To do this, we can write a function that operators on a single `HTML_element` at a time:

```
strip_font_element :: HTML_element -> [HTML_element]
strip_font_element (HTML_font inner) = inner
strip_font_element any_other_element = [any_other_element]
```

And this matches the type we want, but it would only strip `HTML_font` elements at the upper-most level, it wouldn't strip out nested `<font>` tags.  Instead, we can use *recursion* to continue to operate on nested elements:

```
strip_font_element :: HTML_element -> [HTML_element]
-- note: concatMap f x == concat (map f x)
strip_font_element (HTML_font inner) = concatMap strip_font_element inner
strip_font_element any_other_element = [any_other_element]
```

Unfortunately, this won't work entirely either.  I've specifically left out the implementation details to recurse down other types of nodes (`HTML_p`, `HTML_ul`, and `HTML_ol` specifically) that contain child nodes.  Can you figure out how to perform this recursion?

---

2. Given the type

```hs
data Mtree a = Mnode a [Mtree a]
```

We want to be able to pretty-print this out with more indentation for deeper nodes.  For this, we will also reach for recursion as our favorite problem solving tool.  First, let's try just printing out each value without worrying about indentation (left to the reader to implement):

```
print_Mtree :: Show a => Mtree a -> IO ()
print_Mtree (Mnode x []) = print x
```

First, we know that if we reach a node that has no children, we don't have to continue any more, just print `x` and stop.  But what if there are child elements?

```
print_Mtree :: Show a => Mtree a -> IO ()
print_Mtree (Mnode x []) = print x
print_Mtree (Mnode x children) = do
    print x
    mapM_ print_Mtree children
```

This uses the function `mapM_`, which takes a monadic action and applies it to a whole list of arguments before returning `IO ()`.  But really if we wanted to, we don't actually have to worry about the base case, since using `mapM_` over an empty list won't do anything:

```
print_Mtree :: Show a => Mtree a -> IO ()
print_Mtree (Mnode x children) = do
    print x
    mapM_ print_Mtree children
```

Now to implement indentation, we'll need a helper function to keep up with how deep we are:

```
print_Mtree_helper :: Show a => Int -> Mtree a -> IO ()
print_Mtree_helper level (Mnode x children) = ???

print_Mtree mtree = print_Mtree_helper 0 mtree
```

And that's it!